# jQuery check if input is same as element with same class

Tags: jquery

I want to check if the value of the input is the same as a div with class of the input value. And when it is the same it has to show up.

```
 $("#submit").click(function(e){

   var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

   console.log($("div").hasClass(tokenValue));

   if(tokenValue == $("div").hasClass(tokenValue)){
       console.log('test');
       $(this).addClass('testClass');
   }
});
```

this is the html:

```
<div class="a6rqc">
   <p>Token:  a6rqc</p>
   <p>Oefeningen lage rug: lagerugklacht Herhalingen:10 Sets:2</p>
   <p>Oefeningen nek: nekklacht Herhalingen:25 Sets:1</p>
</div>

<div class="f5wfv">
   <p>Token:  f5wfv</p>
   <p>Oefeningen lage rug: lagerugklacht Herhalingen:15 Sets:2</p>
   <p>Oefeningen nek: nekklacht Herhalingen:20 Sets:2</p>
   <p>Oefeningen schouder: schouderklacht Herhalingen:30 Sets:1</p>
</div>
```

So basically when the input text value is the same as the class: a6rqc or f5wfv than it has to show the div

Comment: `$("div").hasClass(tokenValue)` would return true or false

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but could you give us some HTML example of what should or shouldn't add the class?

Comment: you just need this `if($("div").hasClass(tokenValue)){console.log}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `if(tokenValue == $("div").hasClass(tokenValue))` is testing string==boolean
  Only works if boolean is true and string is truthy or if boolean is false and string is falsy
- you are adding testClass to the submit button

---

If you want to add testClass to a div with the entered class, this will work

```
 var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();
 $("div."+tokenValue).addClass("testClass"); // or .show()
```

Comment: I was about to write an answer with the simpler version of code shown above. This is the easiest way to do it, no if's required.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to check if the value of the input is the same as a div with
>   class of the input value. And when it is the same it has to show up.

you're incorrectly comparing a `string` value against a `boolean` value:

```
if(tokenValue == $("div").hasClass(tokenValue))
```

what you want is this:

```
var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();

if($("div").hasClass(tokenValue)){
    console.log('test');
    $(this).addClass('testClass');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On submit get the `input` value and compare it to the div `class` `attribute`.

1-In case if your div has one class name, you can use:

```js
 $("#submit").click(function(e){
  if($('div').attr('class')==$('.valueToken').val()){
       console.log('token value matches the div class name');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="something"></div>
<input value="" class="valueToken">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

2- In case your required div has more than one class name you can use `hasClass` method.

```
 $("#submit").click(function(e){
  if($('div').hasClass($('.valueToken').val())){
       console.log('token value matches the div class name');
   }
});
```

After updating your question, I recommand that you skip the if clause and just try get the required div by its class name and show it if it exists:

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){
   $('div').hide();//initially hide all divs
   $("div."+tokenValue).show(); // only show the required div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($("div[class='"+tokenValue+"']").length>0) {
  $("div[class='"+tokenValue+"']").addClass('testClass');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("div").hasClass(tokenValue)`
 It return true or false when class is present or not present respectively.

`tokenValue == $("div").hasClass(tokenValue)`
   This is wrong because it will be like `if(foo == true)` which will be false always.

you can try this code

```
$("#submit").click(function(e){ 
    var tokenValue = $('.valueToken').val();
    if($("div").hasClass(tokenValue)){ 
        $(this).addClass('testClass');
    }
});
```

Comment: `""==false`,  `0==false`, `null==false`; `" "==true`, `123==true`